# Failed to get Amazon EC2 instance ID

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, cmd, wget

I try to get the instance id with the command line:

```
C:\wgetdown>wget -q -O - http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/instance-id //I puted my real IP address
```

and the CMD thinks a lot of time and nothing happened.. what can be the problem?

Comment: On the instance itself?

Comment: You need to `PUT http://169.254.169.254/latest/api/token` first which will return a token. This is the value for a header called `X-aws-ec2-metadata-token`. Set the header on your above `wget` request and it should work.

Comment: Are you running that command on the Amazon EC2 instance itself? What do you mean by "I put my real IP address"?

Comment: I running on CMD. meybe I don't run it well? and the PUT request  - in the command prompt or postman or another?